# I can't find my Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 14.04. I need my data!

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, windows-7, data-recovery

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 on my laptop (500 Gb hdd). In the partition step there were 3 partitions (recovery partition, hp tools, and the one I had Windows on it).

I selected on "new partition table", as a result I got one partition  (of 500 GB free space). Then I created a new partition (of 25000 GB,type: logical, ext4 journaling file system).

The installation went perfectly and Ubuntu is running perfectly.

However, when I reboot it goes to Ubuntu, and I can't find my Windows 7 option on the GRUB menu. Also, I can't find my recovery and Windows partitions. I don't have my Windows installation on a DVD, only the recovery partition.

I am afraid that my data on Windows are gone. Is there a way to boot to Windows without losing my data?

Comment: Chances are slim that you'll see that data again, sorry. Without the partition table it's extremely hard to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a slight chance of recovering your data if the recovery partition was at the end of your disk using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/286206/344926).

Otherwise, contact the manufacturer of your PC and ask them to send you a "recovery DVD".

**This recovery DVD will wipe your entire drive, so back up your data before continuing!**